# Can not create user with has_secure_password via HttpPost

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I wrote an API with rails. For my user model I enabled the has_secure_password. To make this work I added a password_digest field to this model.

Additionally I added "password" and "password_confirmation" to the permitted parameters. Sending an HttpPost via an Android app does not add password and password_confirmation from the JSONObject to my user. It looks like this:

```
  Parameters: {"lastName"=>"", "club_id"=>0, "email"=>"test", "street"=>"",     "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "userName"=>"test", "firstName"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "city"=>""
  "user"=>{"userName"=>"test", "firstName"=>"", "lastName"=>"", "city"=>"", "street"=>"", "email"=>"test", "club_id"=>0}}
```

Now I wonder why the user has no password / password confirmation. My user_params method looks like this:

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:userName, :firstName, :lastName, :email, :club_id, :street, :city, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

If I send this HttpPost via curl everything works fine. At the moment I do not really know what to do anymore.

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: Move "password" and "password_confirmation" fields to "user" object. Your `user_params` require object `:user`, which represent by "user" object from JSON. And, currently, "user" does not contain "password" and "password_confirmation".

Comment: I do not quite understand how you mean this? How can i move password and password_confirmation to the "user"?
The first Parameters I get are from the app. The "user"=> is what my server makes out of it. But there is not password in my user hash.

Comment: You wrote: "Android app does not add password and password_confirmation from the JSONObject to my user" - so, just add those fields to "user" object in your Android app. Or, you can access password / confirmation via additional method, say `def pwd_paras; params.permit(:password, :password_confirmation); end`. You can merge params like that: `user_params.merge!(pwd_params)`. Check the documentation on strong parameters http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters